# Is there any difference between these compilers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sorting, gcc

I run the same code in different environments.

First one is IDE(visual studio 2017).
Second one is gcc 4.8.5 provided webcompiler.

But, I got different results!

Here is the sample code I run.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

class Data
{
public:
    int num1;
    int num2;
    Data(int _num1, int _num2)
    {
        num1 = _num1;
        num2 = _num2;
    }
    bool operator<(const Data &input) const
    {
        if (this->num1 < input.num1)return true;
        else return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> vec;

    vec.push_back(Data(5, 3));
    vec.push_back(Data(6, 0));
    vec.push_back(Data(6, 1));
    vec.push_back(Data(6, 2));
    vec.push_back(Data(6, 4));
    vec.push_back(Data(9, 5));
    vec.push_back(Data(12, 6));
    vec.push_back(Data(14, 7));
    vec.push_back(Data(16, 8));
    vec.push_back(Data(16, 10));
    vec.push_back(Data(18, 9));
    vec.push_back(Data(20, 11));
    vec.push_back(Data(20, 12));
    vec.push_back(Data(21, 14));
    vec.push_back(Data(22, 13));
    vec.push_back(Data(24, 15));
    vec.push_back(Data(25, 18));
    vec.push_back(Data(26, 16));
    vec.push_back(Data(25, 17));
    vec.push_back(Data(28, 19));
    vec.push_back(Data(30, 20));
    vec.push_back(Data(29, 21));
    vec.push_back(Data(31, 23));
    vec.push_back(Data(32, 22));
    vec.push_back(Data(34, 24));
    vec.push_back(Data(34, 26));
    vec.push_back(Data(36, 25));
    vec.push_back(Data(36, 27));
    vec.push_back(Data(38, 28));
    vec.push_back(Data(38, 30));
    vec.push_back(Data(40, 29));
    vec.push_back(Data(41, 32));
    vec.push_back(Data(42, 31));
    vec.push_back(Data(42, 34));
    vec.push_back(Data(44, 33));
    vec.push_back(Data(46, 35));


    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

When I tried to print element of vec, 
With IDE I got below result.

5 3

6 0

6 1

6 2

6 4

9 5

12 6
.....

But with gcc I got below result.

5 3 

6 0 

6 4 

6 2 

6 1 

9 5 

12 6
.....

Comment: You can modify `operator<` to compare the 2nd numbers when the first ones are equal. Ex: `return num1 == input.num1 ? num2 < input.num2 : num1 < input.num1;`

Comment: Different vendors are not required to use the exact same sorting algorithm for `std::sort`. - It's comPiler, by the way (with a lower-case p).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is both [std::stable_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) and [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) in the standard C++ library**, and for good reason. If both where the same, only one would have been standardized.

If you want a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), use `std::stable_sort`. If you want a fast sort, use just `std::sort` and leave more freedom to your implementation. Don't expect different compilers to give the exact same result when the C++ standard permits some freedom to them.

**Be aware that a programming language is a *specification***, written in English. Spend more time in reading your favorite C++ standard, such as [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) for [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). Be aware of both [unspecified behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) and the much more dangerous [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> Second one is gcc 4.8.5

Be aware that **[GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) is an obsolete unsupported compiler**. The current version of GCC is, since may 2019, [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/). I strongly recommend using a recent GCC compiler (at least [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) in summer 2019).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I get exact answer I want